# Autoincrement created folder names from Access VBA

Tags: vba, for-loop, ms-access, auto-increment, mkdir

I'm wondering if there's a way that I can autoincrement file folder names based off of a value in a form. Basically, I need to create an empty folder within a previous folder with an autoincrementing number for future entries. My script works to create the folder in the right place, but I'm not sure how to make the title of the folder start with "1" then autoincrement for each future entry.

This is what I have right now. It doesn't work, but I think I may be onto something? I know I'll have to make the TimeDateTeam.value something static, or else each folder will be different and not be able to increment on number. I may just omit this entirely, and have the folder be titled "Test n", where n is the autoincremented number.

```
 Dim filepath1 As String
    Dim filepath2 As String
    Dim i As Integer
    
    
    filepath1 = Path2 & "\" & Me!TimeDateTeam.Value & "Test " & i
    filepath2 = Path2 & "\" & Me!TimeDateTeam.Value & "Test " & i + 1
    
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Set fso = New FileSystemObject
    
    If fso.FileExists(filepath1) = True Then
    MkDir filepath1
    
    Else: MkDir filepath2
    End If
```

I'm new to VBA and programming in general, and considered using a for loop and tacking "i" onto the end as long as i > 1, but I'm not sure the syntax to complete this. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I am not set on using a for loop, so please help if you have another way!

Comment: What do you mean by 'does not work' - error message, wrong result, nothing happens? Dates are normally structured with `/` character which cannot be in folder or file name. Format the date value to remove.

Comment: If file exists, why would you then try to create it? Seems need to swap the MkDir variables. Is Path2 a Global variable? How many folders do you want to create? Will this be determined by user input? Will this always be a new set of folders or will you need to add to a parent folder?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```vb
Sub Tester()

    Const root As String = "C:\Tester\Test\"
    Dim i As Integer
    
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Set fso = New FileSystemObject
    
    i = 1
    Do While fso.FolderExists(root & "Subfolder" & i)
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    fso.CreateFolder (root & "Subfolder" & i)
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not need a reference to the FileSystemObject.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Sub sbMkDir()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim s As String
    s = CurrentProject.Path & "\folder"
    For i = 1 To 3
        MkDir s & i
    Next i
End Sub
```

Works in Windows 10 and Microsoft 365